# How can I calculate the following partial derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy^3}{x^2 + y^2} & \text{if }(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\
\\
0 & \text{if }(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}$$

Find $f_x(0,0)$, $f_y(0,0)$, $f_{xy}(0,0)$.

Comment: @ user95616:  I edited your post by "Latexifying" it.  Hope that's OK; hope I got the math right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{h\to 0, h \ne 0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}&=&0=f_x(0,0),\\
\lim_{h\to 0,h \ne 0}\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}&=&0=f_y(0,0),\\
f_{x}(x,y)&=&\frac{y^3(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \quad \forall (x,y) \ne (0,0),\\
\lim_{h\to0,h\ne 0}\frac{f_x(0,h)-f_x(0,0)}{h}&=&\lim_{h\to0,h\ne 0}\frac{h}{h}=1
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Remember when you are calculating a partial derivative of $x$, treat $y$ as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of the derivative, not formulas like the Quotient Rule, etc. For instance,

$$f_x(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$$

You probably need to treat this problem in this way, because the function is piece-wise defined. Writing $f_x(x,y)=\frac{(x^2+y^2)y^3-xy^3(2x)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ and proceeding from there would be a fine application of the Quotient Rule, but it is only valid for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f_{xy}(0,0)=\lim_{k\to0}\frac{f_x(0, k)-f_x(0,0)}{k}=\displaystyle \lim_{k\to0}\frac{\frac{k^5}{k^4}}{k}=1.$$